# Validate echo PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to validate my output data from a php site that Im calling with

```
<?php include_once('nav.inc.php');
?>
```

The thing is when Im using this code

```
<ul>
<li><a href="gb.php">GÄSTBOK</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php">OM MIG</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.php">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li><a href="cv.php">CURRICULUM VITAE</a></li>
</ul>
```

I wont get any errors, But when Im trying with the other code I get alot of errors. Is there any way to write the code so It validates ?

This is the code thas bugging me

```
<?php 
$index = 'menu';
$gb = 'menu';
$portfolio = 'menu';
$cv = 'menu';
$menuLinkid=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php');
if($menuLinkid=='index'){
$index = 'myButtons';
}else if($menuLinkid=='gb'){
        $gb ='myButtons';
}else if($menuLinkid=='portfolio'){
        $portfolio ='myButtons';
}else if($menuLinkid=='cv'){
$cv ='myButtons';
}
?>

<div id="fronticon">
<a href="contact.php"><img src="images/em.png" alt="Email" title="Email"/>
</a> 
</div>

<ul>
<li><a class="<?php echo $index; ?> "href="index.php">OM MIG</a></li>
<li><a class="<?php echo $gb; ?> "href="gb.php">GÄSTBOK</a></li>
<li><a class="<?php echo $portfolio;?> " href="portfolio.php">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
<li><a class="<?php echo $cv; ?> "href="cv.php">CURRICULUM VITAE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "validate" exactly? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Well, what do the errors say?

Comment: You *really* need to sort out the positioning of the closing double quotes in your `<li>`s - `"href="index.php"` is not likely to work at all... should be `" href="index.php"`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need spaces between the ?> " and the href. You can't have them next to each other with no space.

Should be:

```
<li><a class="<?php echo $index; ?> " href="index.php">OM MIG</a></li>
```

Comment: so that tiny space was such a big problem :) thank you my friend :)